# Find the longest northeast path in $O(n\log n)$ time

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, computational-geometry

Given a set $Z$ of $n$ points $(p_1,p_2,p_3, \ldots,p_n)$. The coordinates of these points are arbitrary numbers and are unsorted. If they give me $s$ and $t$ to be two points in $Z$. A northeast path from $s$ to $t$ in $Z$ is a sequence of points $(s=t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k=t)$ such that every point for any two points $t_i$ and $t_{i + 1}$, $t_{i + 1}$ is on the northeast of $t_i$ (i.e., $x(t_i) \leq x(t_{i+1})$ and $y(t_i) \leq y(t_{i+1})$).
Design an $O(n \log n)$ time algorithm to compute a longest northeast path $P (s, t)$ from $s$ to $t$ in the set $Z$.

So far I have considered the sweeping algorithm to traverse the plane and register every point as an event, then calculate the distance between the points of the sweep line and $t$. But I think this is not feasible since I have to consider all the points in the sweep line and calculate each distance. I do not know how to approach this problem and I would like suggestions.

Comment: I didn't really read the question, but can it have something to do with the convex hull?

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this problem, or the motivation for solving it?  Can you credit the original source/resource where you saw this?  And tell us what topics were being explained/studied in that resource, right before this problem?

Comment: What is the measure by which $(s=t_1,t_2,…,t_k=t)$ is *longest*? Maximal $k$? It can't be $L^1$ distance. Sum of Euclidean distances?

Comment: I assume we have to transform the points to coordinates

Comment: "transform the points to coordinates" - what do you mean?